# SQL Oracle datetime string format filter

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime-format

In oracle, I have table called Ship as shown below;

The date and time are present in a single column as string format.

```
f_ID      f_type    f_date

1001      A 3/30/14 12:00:44 PM

1001      B 3/30/14 10:05:45 AM

1002      A 2/4/14 11:31:11 AM

1002      B 2/3/14 9:43:21 AM

1003      A 2/3/14 9:37:04 AM

1003      B 12/13/14 10:13:43 AM

1004      A 2/3/14 10:49:50 AM

1005      B 2/3/14 11:00:43 AM

1006      A 2/3/13 11:02:28 AM

1006      B 2/3/14 11:07:23 AM

1006      C 2/3/14 9:19:11 AM

1007      A 2/4/14 11:32:30 AM

1007      B 2/4/14 11:32:30 AM

1007      C 2/4/14 11:32:30 AM

1007      D 2/4/14 11:32:30 AM
```

I wish to query/list IDs (`f_ID`) which only have exact date for each record, but the time stamps can be different.

How can I query this in Oracle?  I'm having difficulty in querying as the date and time are merged in a single column.

The result should be

```
f_ID    f_type  f_date

1001    A   3/30/14

1001    B   3/30/14

1004    A   2/3/14 

1005    B   2/3/14 

1007    A   2/4/14 

1007    B   2/4/14 

1007    C   2/4/14 

1007    D   2/4/14
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of `s_id` and dates, use an aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select s.s_id, trunc(date), count(*)
from ship s
group by s.s_id, trunc(date)
having min(date) <> max(date)
```

EDIT:

If your date is a string, then you should fix the data.  The format that you have is awful.  If you *have* to store a date as a string, *always* use the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS format (or something similar).  But you can still do what you want:

```
select s.s_id, substr(date, 1, instr(date, ' ')), count(*)
from ship s
group by s.s_id, substr(date, 1, instr(date, ' '))
having min(date) <> max(date)
```

Comment: shows "ORA-01722: invalid number" on line 3 at TRUNC(date). I'm using taod.

Comment: Is your date not stored in a datetime format?  Is it a string?

Comment: unfortunately, it is a string.

Comment: Could you please explain me the logic of min(date) <> max(date)?

Comment: @Chino . . . You want the time stamps to be different.  So this checks that the "date" value (which contains a time stamp) has at least two different values on a given day.

Comment: OK, can you please tell me how can I do sum of all count(*) as mentioned in your query above? I want to know the sum of all counts where more than one shipment was done on any given day.

Comment: @Chino . . . I don't know what you mean.  If you have another question, you can ask it as another question (if related to this one, you can refer to this one in the description).

Comment: Please refer to the results in the description, I want a query to get the result 8. This number is the total # where at least two shipments were made on any given day.

Comment: @Chino . . . Just use this query as a subquery and do `select count(*) from (<subquery>) s`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
select f_ID, f_type, trunc(f_date) f_date
from Ship
order by f_date;
```

This will allow you to detect the lines with same date, whatever the timestamp.

Comment: I do not understand dday. Please see my post edited where i have shown the expected results after querying.

Comment: See my edit, this should be ok now. Actually, dday was just a column alias (I used dday instead of day which is a reserved keyword in Oracle).

Comment: I'm getting following error "ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement" on TRUNC.  I'm using toad on oracle.

Comment: I'm sorry but this exact query on the same table gives me the correct results... Are you sure you execute exactly the same query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the time using the `TRUNC` function:

```
SELECT fdid
FROM ship
WHERE TRUNC(ship.date_field) = SOME_DATE;
```

If you just want to get all the possible dates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(TRUNC(date_field))
FROM ship;
```

Comment: Thanks pablomatico. But I wish to have a list for all possible dates. How can I do that?

Comment: Only the possible dates?

Comment: All the possible Dates,

Comment: Please allow me to explain further; I only wish to list the IDs, which have all the dates equal, the result should be  f_ID f_type f_date
1001 A 3/30/14
1001 B 3/30/14
1004 A 2/3/14 
1005 B 2/3/14 
1007 A 2/4/14 
1007 B 2/4/14 
1007 C 2/4/14 
1007 D 2/4/14

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need:

```
Select f_id, f_type, SubStr(f_date, 1, InStr(f_date, ' '))
From Ship s 
Where Exists( Select 1
                From Ship x 
               Where SubStr(s.f_date, 1, InStr(s.f_date, ' ')) = 
                     SubStr(x.f_date, 1, InStr(x.f_date, ' '))
                 And s.f_date <> x.f_date )
Order By f_id, f_type
```

Comment: Thank Matheus, I'm using taod for oracle, and its giving me the following error "ORA-01722: invalid number" for Trunc(x.f_date) on line# 5.  Please advise.